# SQL Join or Update command

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL and i am trying to do this update.

I have 2 database called Arcadia1 and Arcadia2.I would like to copy a specific column value from specific table from arcadia 2 to arcadia 1 but where id are matching

for example my database looks like this.(Database:Arcadia,Table:Skill,first column: Column:id,2nd column:var1)

Comment: You need to provide more information like if both tables have data, sample data and what result you want to get.

Comment: Both tables have data,but they are diffrent values,i would like to make a query that would update all new values from 2nd database to first where my id are matching.but I did mostly this by hand since i am realy realy  new to sql

Comment: Please make your explanation by showing some sample data and expected output, otherwise I don't understand it (and unlikely that someone would).

Comment: Blindly, it would look like Update Arcadia1.dbo.Skill set var1 = t2.var1 from Arcadia2.dbo.Skill t2 where id = t2.id;

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Update f1
set f1.var1 = f2.var1 
from Arcadia1.dbo.Skill f1 
inner join Arcadia2.dbo.Skill f2 on f1.id = f2.id and isnull(f1.var1, '')<>isnull(f2.var1, '')
```